# How to add testers in Apple Developer Account?

Tags: ios, testflight, apple-developer

There is a major issue in Apple Developer Account where "Testers and Groups" for particular application we packaged and installed to itunes are disabled, and I do not have the access to add user in that section.

But if I goto

Itunes -> "Users & Roles" -> "Itunes Connect Users" had my Admin, Legal account already without me creating it. And I managed to add accounts there but when ever the accounts we add over here are not displayed in   "Testers and Groups" under application

I have attached screen shots for references.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did your Testers accept any invitation that iTunesConnect sent them?  Their names won't appear under "Add iTunesConnect Users" until they have signed in and/or agreed to some terms & conditions.  Also, iTunesConnect's logic might not enable Adding Testers because you currently have "No Builds".

Comment: @MichaelDautermann This appears when I try to add testers to my uploaded App. Then it has disabled adding any testers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure -

1. You have added your `bundle id` in your [apple account](https://developer.apple.com/).
2. You have managed to add all the required `certifications`.
3. After that you have select the `bundle id` then you register your app in `iTunesConnect`.

**For more** - [Reference_1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tydk4Fc-tg) [Reference_2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91sTQ39kkK4&t=201s)

Answer (score 0):

There is no special group like "Tester Roles" you have to assign the Developer role so he/she can get the invitation.

Check this two things for **Internal Tester**

1. Given Email id is apple ID or not ?
2. And while assign the role you have to choose specific app or you can assign all app also in what user to test all your app.

**For External Tester**

1. You have to submit your application to Apple for review
2. After successful review from Apple, you can add as many Testers' email ids as you want